# How to get fragment activity multiple times without crashes?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment where I need its activity multiple times. I am calling `requireActivity()`, something like this:

```
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        try {
            val manager = Manager()
            manager.analyze(requireActivity())
            manager.setNumbers(requireActivity())
        }
        catch (e: Exception) {

        }
        mBinding = NewFragmentBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        return mBinding.root
    }
```

Currently, I am keeping the code inside try catch to prevent the `IllegalStateException` crash. The problem is that I need to pass activity in multiple places. I don't want to use try catch everywhere. I could use `getActivity()`, but it returns `null` if the fragment is detached from the `Activity` and some methods don't accept `null` values. Also, passing activity to the fragment constructor could cause memory leaks. How are you guys solving this problem?

Comment: You never need a try catch inside `onCreateView` as `requireActivity()` is always valid to call in lifecycle callbacks. What makes you think that would ever cause a crash?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I just shared an example. I need activity in multiple places, not just in onCreateView.

Comment: If you're doing anything after your fragment is destroyed, that's already a memory leak you need to fix. If you have an example of one of those places, maybe include that in your question?